# $\forall x \in S, \big( \phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x) \big)$ versus $\forall x , \big( \phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x) \big)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Consider the two first order symbolic statements:

$$\forall x \in S, \big( \phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x) \big)$$

and

$$\forall x , \big( \phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x) \big)$$

I interpret the **first statement** as saying, "For all objects in set $S$, one of three scenarios must be true for an arbitrary $x^* \in S$:

1. if a specific $x^* \in S$ satisfies the $\phi$ property, then $x^*$ satisfies the $\phi'$ property.
2. if a specific $x^* \in S$ does **not** satisfy the $\phi$ property, then $x^*$ satisfies the $\phi'$ property.
3. if a specific $x^* \in S$ does **not** satisfy the $\phi$ property, then $x^*$ does **not** satisfy the $\phi'$ property.

I believe this is correct.

---

Now, more and more I am beginning to see symbolic statements of the **second form**, where there is no set that the $\forall x$ specifically refers to. How should I interpret this? I am becoming more acquainted with set theory (Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory, specifically) and so am reluctant to say that this particular $\forall x$ is referencing the universe.

At the moment, the only remedy I have implemented to address this confusion is by noticing that the set for which the $\forall x$ references is often times ***embedded*** within one of the $\phi$ statements. So, what I really do is "remove" that embedded property from $\phi$ and take it out to where the $\forall x$ symbol is located. In doing this, I feel like I am effectively changing the $\phi$ statement to some *new statement* $\psi$ (where...in a *very* brutally informal way "$\psi=\phi - \text{set for which x references}"$...i.e. $\psi$ retains all property descriptions of $\phi$ besides the set for which $x$ references.

Is this the correct approach...or do universal quantifiers not necessarily need to reference a specific set? If so, how exactly should I interpret the second statement? Any clarity would be greatly appreciated! Cheers~

Comment: The universal quantifier quantifies over all sets, that's why it's universal. Writing $\forall x\in S...$ is just a shortcut for $\forall x(x\in S\rightarrow...)$.

Comment: @Thorgott I’m not sure I know what you mean by “all sets”...do you mean all sets that are referenced in $\phi$ with respect to x?

Comment: "All sets" means, well, everything. In ZFC, sets are all there is, and $\forall x \psi(x)$ means that every object has the property $\psi(x)$.

Comment: @Reveillark hmmmm. So even though there is no such thing as a universal set in ZFC, we can reference all objects contained within it?

Comment: There is no universal set in ZFC, correct. In that vein, your last "it" is problematic, because there is no "it". The universal quantifier ranges over all the objects you could possibly be talking about. Writing $\forall x\in S \phi(x)$ is a shorthand for $\forall x(x\in S\to \phi(x))$ which says "for any $x$, if $x$ is in $S$, then $x$ has property $\phi$". We're not referring to the collection of things contained in a non-existent universal set, but rather to the entirety of all things, if that makes sense

Comment: @Reveillark thank you! I found a nice follow up here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132274/what-does-universal-quantification-mean

Comment: @Reveillark just for clarification, $\forall x \Big(x \in S \rightarrow \big(\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x) \big)\Big)$ is the "real version" of $\forall x \in S, \big( \phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x) \big)$, yes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: @Reveillark i have one more for you, if you'd oblige. Does the short hand "$\forall x \in S$" also apply to "$\exists x \in S $"...i.e. does $\exists x \in S \phi(x)$ mean "$\exists x \big(x \in S \rightarrow \phi(x)\big)$"

Comment: Not quite, the situation is slightly different for the existential case: $\exisis x\in S\phi(x)$ is a shorthand for $\exists x(x\in S \wedge \phi(x))$. This makes sense, as it captures the desired meaning of $\exisis x\in S \phi(x)$